# object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I get this hibernate error(in the title), when I turn off the cascading`(Cascade.ALL)` and start to manually `em.persist()` the lower-in-the-hierarchy entities. So this is not possible at all?
I'm sure that the entities are persistent before, they are even in the database, but I get this error.
How to fix it?
EDIT:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: cz.domain.model.PlayerInMatch.player -> cz.domain.model.Player
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1176)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1112)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$1.beforeCompletion(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1008)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:412)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:837)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5040)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4805)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2004)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1955)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:198)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
        at $Proxy202.create(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalSlsbInvokerInterceptor.invokeInContext(LocalSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:71)
        at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.invoke(AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:189)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy205.create(Unknown Source)
        at cz.domain.controller.Controllers.persistMatch(Controllers.java:29)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:174)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: cz.domain.model.PlayerInMatch.player -> cz.domain.model.Player
        at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.noCascade(CascadingAction.java:387)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:172)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:451)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:158)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:818)
        at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:451)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:158)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:818)
        at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
        at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$1.beforeCompletion(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1001)
        ... 56 more
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I (...) start to manually em.persist() the lower-in-the-hierarchy entities.

Are you sure. Hibernate is clearly complaining about an attribute being **transient**.

> So this is not possible at all?

It is.

> I'm sure that the entities are persistent before, they are even in the database, but I get this error.

What? How did you construct the object graph then? Can you show your code?

Comment: it works after switching to hibernate. I will switch back to hibernate to show the code in some days